# Is fast setting concrete heavier than regular concrete?

Tags: concrete

I used the fast setting concrete to hold an umbrella clothes line inside a five gallon bucket, but someone told me that the fast setting concrete wasn't as heavy as regular concrete.

If regular concrete is heavier than fast setting concrete, then which type of concrete is the heaviest?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 2):

The person that told you that regular concrete is heavier than fast setting concrete may be referring to the weight of the bags that they come in at the big box stores.  The weight in concrete comes mostly from the aggregate, not the cement.  Any difference in weight between the two types of concrete would be immaterial in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Fast setting concrete should be no more or less dense than regular concrete.  Fast setting concrete is typically made by using more finely ground cement and/or chemical additives that make it set up faster (chlorides or thiocyanides).  In either case, this has a negligible affect on the density.